# Как использовать Selenium для SRWare Iron?

Tags: python, selenium

Я новичок в Selenium. И знаю как взаимодействовать с Хромом, но как и возвожно ли вообще как то взаимодействовать с SRWare Iron?

Answer (score 0):

О `Selenium` можно почитать здесь: http://python-3.ru/page/selenium-python-example (рус) 
или здесь: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html (eng).
Судя по всему, нужно найти `webdriver` для Вашего браузера (если такой существует).

На англоязычной версии стэка есть обсуждение данного вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386687/is-it-posible-to-use-selenide-with-srware-iron-browser

**Update**
Так как SRWare Iron - это допиленный Chrome, то можно сделать так:

1) Скачать portabler версию SRWare Iron;

2) Переименовать файл IronPortable.exe в Chrome.exe

3) Скачать вебдрайвер для Хрома (я скачал для 74 релиза): http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

4) Закинуть файл chromedriver.exe в папку с Iron Portable;

5) Добавить путь к папке с портабл версией Iron в PATH (как это сделать, можно почитать здесь: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

6) перегрузить комп;

7) в программе использовать код для Chrome (при этом удалить путь к chrome из path, если он там присутствует):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```